# Blur text in Canvas 2d

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, three.js

How can I make a text drawn using canvas 2d more clear (context.fillText).

Below is an screenshot of a blur text I want to fix. Screenshot is taken using latest version of Chrome on Mac. The output is blur in any browser I tried.

I am using three.js and to write text on the screen, I am using canvas2d.

When I zoom into the page by moving the camera close to objects, all canvas elements become more and more blur.

Any ideas how can I fix this ?

You can also see that the text is blur here:

http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Texture-From-Canvas.html

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are creating a texture for the text, the only way really is to increase your texture resolution. Whats happening currently is you are taking a small texture and stretching it, which makes it blurry, the same thing happens when you stretch an image thumbnail to full size for example.

*Ignore the unloaded textures, the black areas, they aren't important for the example*

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/b3nu3/)**

What I did to increase the clarity of the texture was create a canvas 600 by 120 (which is double the size this demo was using), draw the text onto it and set the `fontsize` to 120px, then I make the mesh 300 by 60, which is half of the textures size.

```
    // Specified the width I wanted 
    canvas1.width=600;
    // Specified the height I wanted
    canvas1.height=120;
    // Made the font larger
    context1.font = "Bold 100px Arial";
    context1.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,0.95)";
    // changed the position of the text on the created canvas
    context1.fillText('Hello, world!', 0, 100);
```

When creating the mesh I just specified how large I wanted the mesh, which was 50% the size of the texture, to match the demos mesh size.

```
    var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.PlaneGeometry(300, 60),
        material1
      );
```